# Failed on Converting Monolithic Spring Boot App with Gradle into Multi Module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, multi-module

Actually I have an monolithic spring boot app with gradle and I want to covert it into multi module.
It just a simple app to do CRUD book.

My app structure like the following,

```
simple-app
| src/main/java/example/simpleapp
| -------------------------------/controller`
| -------------------------------/exception
| -------------------------------/model
| -------------------------------/repository
| -------------------------------/service
| -------------------------------SimpleAppAplication
| build.gradle
| settings.gradle
```

step by step I separate all the package into module,
then my folder structure changed to like the following

```
simple-app
| controller
| | src
| | build.gradle
| exception
| | src
| | build.gradle
| main-app
| | src
| | build.gradle
| model
| | src
| | build.gradle
| repository
| | src
| | build.gradle
| service
| | src
| | build.gradle
| build.gradle
| settings.gradle
```

if I run the project, It working just fine and return the result that should be return.

But, when I build the project, It turn into error like this.

```
PC:~/simple-app$ ./gradlew build
> Task :repository:compileJava FAILED
/simple-appp/repository/src/main/java/example/simpleapp/repository/BookRepository.java:3: error: package nanihutagaol.simpleapp.model does not exist
import example.simpleapp.model.Book;
                               ^
simple-app/repository/src/main/java/example/simpleapp/repository/BookRepository.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {
                                                  ^
symbol: class Book
2 errors
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':repository:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
BUILD FAILED in 2s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

I don't understand why it turn error like that, because the model package was exist. Hope one of you can give an solution.

thanks before...

`edited:`

on repository/build.gradle

```
group = 'example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
  implementation project(":model")
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
}
```

on model/build.gradle

```
group = 'example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
configurations {
  compileOnly {
    extendsFrom annotationProcessor
  }
}
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
}
```

Comment: Do you have the project dependencies configured for each sub-project? (Eg. `repository` should probably have the `model` dependency.) Maybe you can share the `build.gradle` file for some of the sub-projects that don't work.

Comment: Yes, I have any kind of dependency for the subproject. I have edited my question with the `build.gradle` of the file that getting error.

Comment: I see that you are using Spring Boot. Are you applying the spring-boot plugin to all projects? For instance in a `subprojects` or `allprojects` block?

Comment: I use it on the root project using subproject, like this

`subprojects {
 apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
 apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
 apply plugin: 'java'
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally can solve the error, after trying to understand other similar topic.

So my first syntax on `root/build.gradle` are as follows

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.0.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
group = 'example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":main-app")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'java'
}
```

Then I update it by adding the following code, on the `root/build.gradle` and `subprojects/build.gradle`

```
bootJar {
  enabled = false
}

jar {
  enabled = true
}
```

Based on guide on https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/, that code used to tell Gradle to not build an executable jar for the Library project.

I don't know why I miss this step before. So, my last `root/build.gradle` will look like

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.0.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":main-app")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'java'

    group = 'example'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    
    bootJar {
        enabled = false
    }

    jar {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Then I update all my `subproject/build.gradle`, by just adding dependencies tag. For example `repository/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":model")
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
}
```

That's all my problem explanation... :)